# Hiding urls in a Rails 3 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, security, url

In an attempt to improve site security, I would like to mask or hide urls in a Rails 3 application. I don't want "friendly" urls. I would prefer that just the domain be displayed in the browser address. I read that it is possible in rails 2 but not in rails 3. If that is true, what else can i do?

UPDATE:
Is hiding ID's the best i can do? If so, what is the best method?

Thanks.

Comment: How would the security be improved by hiding URLs? All this would do is reduce your site usability.

Comment: As a security rule of thumb, only do things that inconvenience attackers more than they inconvenience legitimate users. The ratio on this one is backwards.

Comment: @user249228, +1 for the rule of thumb

Comment: @Jay Have you seen many such "secure" sites? Poor url-hackers, prepare to loose your job, unless you're able to look into html source.

Comment: @RocketR, I regularly view source as i am developing. And we check our logs to deny access to ip addys that attempt obvious hacking attempts. I was just trying to make it a little more inconvenient for the mischievous that did not have a great deal of expertise.

Comment: @Jay I often try "obvious hacking attempts" just of curiousity. But the real threat are the guys who won't even notice your "little inconveniencies". IMHO, you are just wasting time instead of actually improving security.

Comment: @RocketR, Ok... thanks. +1 lick from Martin... see my gravatar... for your honest opinion and persistence on the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out some authorization solutions. [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) has worked for me in the past and is simple to implement.

EDIT: After reading your question this doesn't do what you want (mask urls), but if your goal is to improve site security implementing an authorization solution is a much cleaner thing to do than just hiding urls from an end user.

Answer (score 1):

Build everything in a frameset. That will hide the URL from the address bar.  But it will do nothing for site security as an attacker can just read the page source and find them anyways. There is no real way to hide the URL from the browser and therefore a dedicated attacker, as the browser is going to need to be told where to go.

Comment: What does the Id matter. No matter what you do you will need some way to indicate what object or page you are looking for.so if a dedicated attacker is hitting your site they will figure out the id or how you are hiding it. This Is all just security by obscurity and is not Really effective against real attacks.