# How to hide the controller and action names in Rails URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I want to hide the controller name and action names in the rails url. I never want 
    to show them. I want the root to be http://localhost:3000 always. 
For Example: If a user clicks on add action or edit action the url should be http://localhost:3000. It should not change at all.

Comment: [you don't want to do this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6595788/hiding-urls-in-a-rails-3-application)

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. You can define whatever routes you want, but you must define some routes so that Rails can route your request. If you have a single-page application (where navigation is handled in JavaScript and content is loaded only via AJAX), then you can simply not navigate to these URLs.

Comment: Simply use AJAX for loading all your pages and have fun :)